# Optimizing multiple SELECTs

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, select

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.vote = 1) AS upvotes,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE votes.vote = -1) AS downvotes,
FROM votes WHERE link = <linkid>
```

Straight up question; how could this be optimized? I can't think of any better way to do it but I'm bad at MySQL.

Thanks for any responses!

**EDIT:** To make things clear: I want it to return one row with two columns; `upvotes` and `downvotes`

Comment: Does that even give you the result you want?

Comment: err, yeah, I  think it does. I adapted that query from a query I use in my code.

Comment: @MarkByers I'm sure it does not!

Comment: This query needs the where clause on the sub-queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using SUM instead of COUNT:

```
SELECT 
  SUM(vote = 1) AS upvotes,
  SUM(vote = -1) AS downvotes
FROM votes WHERE link = <linkid>
```

Note that this does *not* give you the same result as the query you posted. I think the query you posted is *wrong*!

Comment: Wait, what does my query do then? What does yours do?

Comment: @Jonathan: Your query gives the total number or positive (`vote=1`) and negative (`vote=-1`) votes, counting ALL the table's rows. All the answers given here, count the positive and negative votes for those rows ONLY that `link=<linkid>`

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT sum(case when vote = 1 then 1 end) as upvotes,
    sum(case when vote = -1 then 1 end) as downvotes
FROM votes
WHERE link = < linkid >
```

Answer (score 1):

I would be using this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), vote AS numvotes FROM votes WHERE vote = -1 OR vote = 1 GROUP BY vote
```

Comment: Smart! Forgot it, thnx @MattFenwick

Comment: This is different -- two rows.

Comment: This does not return a result the way OP expects. OP expects two columns: one for upvotes and one for downvotes. Your query will return 0, 1 or 2 lines, depending on the existing data.

Comment: It's different but it may be faster (or slower) than other options. And it's not difficult to change the application code or the query to show results in same format.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(case vote when  1 then 1 else null end) AS upvotes,
  COUNT(case vote when -1 then 1 else null end) AS downvotes
FROM votes WHERE link = <linkid>
```

Time to learn: `count` only counts non-nulls, so whenever you see `then 1` might as well be `then 'Yay!'`. Nulls are not counted.

Answer (score 1):

I guess all commentors meant that your query should probably be:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE link = <linkid> AND vote = 1 ) AS upvotes,
  (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE link = <linkid> AND vote = -1) AS downvotes
```

By now, you have at least 4 other ways that do the same as this one (3 ways exactly this and 1 way slightly different, giving the same results but in 2 rows). Test with your data and choose the faster (or keep them all and test again later, when the table grows bigger).

A composite index on `(link,vote)` would also be useful for all versions.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO , you should not be calculating the total vote count on a fly **at all**. Instead you should store the **total vote count** with the item, and use the detailed vote log as a tool for ensuring the integrity of to results and give the users ability to withdraw the vote.

Comment: @Hogan: Never is a very strong word. When the elections are over, I wouldn't want my queries to count all votes again and again, every time a user wants to see results. Duplicate aggregate data is not always bad, on the contrary (especially when they won't change - or sometimes when ultra speed is needed without 100% accuracy)

Comment: I doubt that every time I go to Obama's Twitter page it runs query that counts 10,000,000 followers.. or YouTube with views.. etc..

Comment: assuming , that you have 1 user able to cast 1 vote on 1 item , in a case of 1000 user voting on 1000 items ( that would be a low-activity forum ) , you will generate 1M entries. And in each page view you would filter&sum them .. most likely multiple times per page. Data duplication and optimization and not incompatible.

Comment: @ypercube (and Thilo) - Caching is different than duplicating.  teresko is not suggesting a new data point be added (results of elections) teresko is suggesting you keep the total and validate it (some number of time / time period.).  Seems like a bad plan.

Comment: @Hogan , yes , when the user is deleted , his votes should be removed too. That is one case, when you recount the total votes (or more likely: count votes made by that user and remove them from total ). And there are other similar situations.

Comment: @Hogan. I did not disagree completely on the -1. But it appeared that you downvoted just because there was duplication. I certainly agree that the plan by teresko is not what I'd consider using, not unless counting was definitely slow. tersešk: exactly because of these complications that need to be added.

Comment: @ypercube - Point taken, my comment should have been "Duplication of data is never good unless you have a really really good reason which is better than the point mentioned here." :[

Comment: @Hogan: Duplication of data happens every single day in every single application (indexes are one form).  [Denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) is a *very* powerful optimization technique.  In this case, I'd keep the votes table going, but add a trigger onAfterInsert and onAfterDelete to keep the up/down votes in track.  That way you can have a summary field to make live queries quite efficient, and still have an audit track.  But teresko's idea isn't downvote worthy.  In fact, it's good advice since that's basically what a very large number of applications do... +1

Comment: Data synchronization issues got you down?  Use triggers!  Seriously @ircmaxell, we are talking about a user who does not know how to use `COUNT`, `SUM` and `CASE` -- you really think they are going to build a robust data tier caching system?  When the system gets big enough to need such caching then is the time to use these advanced techniques.  99% of websites will never need it in the real world.  (Unless they make use of crazy sub-queries and other sub-optimal techniques.)  Basics first!